# Uncaught exception: Bad options value: must be array of arrays, either each with two strings or each with three strings

Tags: javascript, exception, mapping

I am getting an error:

> "uncaught exception: Bad options value: must be an array of arrays, either each with two strings or each with three strings"

when I run this function :

```
return options.map(function (option) {
        if (option)
            {
                option == option.replace("/", " ");
                return option;
            }
            else {
                return option == null;
            }
    });
```

While the below one-liner function works fine without any error :

```
return options.map(function (option) {
  return option !== null ? [option, option.replace("/", " ")] : null; });
```

Can someone tell me what is this cause of the error and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Note that the result of these two are different.

In the first case the `map` is returning an array of "strings or null"

In the second case the `map` is returning and array of "arrays of length 2 or boolean"

also if `option` is undefined, the empty string or 0 they will behave differently since these are all falsy

do a console.log before returning to see the differences.